# Why in הא לחמא עניא do we invite people to come to our seder table while the seder is going on?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Why in הא לחמא עניא do we invite people to come to our seder table while the seder is going on? Shouldn’t we invite people before Pesach? Isn’t this statement insincere?

> הָא לַחְמָא עַנְיָא דִּי אֲכָלוּ אַבְהָתָנָא בְּאַרְעָא דְמִצְרָיִם
>   כָּל דִּכְפִין יֵיתֵי וְיֵיכוֹל
>   כָּל דִּצְרִיךְ יֵיתֵי וְיִפְסַח
>   הָשַׁתָּא הָכָא – לְשָׁנָה הַבָּאָה בְּאַרְעָא דְיִשְׂרָאֵל
>   הָשַׁתָּא עַבְדֵּי – לְשָׁנָה הַבָּאָה בְּנֵי חוֹרִין.

Comment: I think that the ויפסח is a problem. Pessach is only limnuyav. And the minuy must be before the hakrava. So what is Veyfsach???
The last is not insincere.

Comment: @kouty. As I say below, this is only zeicher lekorbon and originally was done before the shechitah. Now we do it to say someone who needs the mitzvah of Pesach should come join us.

Comment: @sabbahillel, yes but how explain you the word "ויפסח"?

Comment: @kouty - Then join the group (before shechitah) Now - keep the mitzvos of Pesach (matza and haggada)

Comment: @sabbahillel Very well. I am very happy because I never understand this. Where is the source of this good perush?

Comment: @kouty see the references that I use in my answer. There are a number of haggados that refere to  this.

Comment: @sabbahillel +1. A good gift for Pessach thank you

Answer (score 4):

There are several points that can be made about this. First, this emphasizes that we are still in galus. If we were free and bringing the karban Pesach, we could not have said this. Additionally, we are making our guests feel better because they see us using "poor man's bread" and it might appear that we cannot afford better. On the other hand, a poor man at the rich man's table would also feel bad.

["Ha Lachma Anya": Rav Moshe Shternbuch - Now You Invite Guests, After Kiddush?](http://revach.net/avodah/ahavas-yisroel/Ha-Lachma-Anya-Rav-Moshe-Shternbuch-Now-You-Invite-Guests-After-Kiddush/3568)

> Rav Moshe Shternbuch answers that the guest are already sitting at our
>   table but they feel really badly about what is going on.  They were
>   invited for the Seder by a man who is also poor.  He sits Seder night
>   with "poor man's bread" on his table.  Chazal instituted Ha Lachma
>   Anya to allay the fears of our poor guest.  We tell him that we are
>   not poor.  The poor bread is simply a remembrance to the days when we
>   were in Mitzrayim.
>
> We then tell him that we have plenty of food to go around and enough
>   to feed him as well, without giving up our own rations.  Therefore,
>   "Kol Dichfin Yeisei V'Yeichol" all the hungry guests are welcome to
>   eat in comfort.
>
> To top it all off we tell him that he should not feel like a pauper at
>   the rich homeowner's table.  "Hashata Avdei", we are all really slaves
>   in this galus.  "L'Shana Haba B'Arya D'Yisroel", next year we should
>   all rejoice together in Eretz Yisroel

Another point is that in order to show that we have been freed, we invite people because a slave owns nothing and can invite no one without stealing from his master. Thus, even though we might be poor and eating "lechem oni" we are still free and we are eating that which belongs to us and which we obtained honestly.

[Understanding ‘Ha Lachma Anya’](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/parsha/understanding-ha-lachma-anya/2015/03/26/)

> The Ritvah in his commentary to the Haggadah suggests that on the
>   night of the Seder every person must envision as if he or she left
>   Mitzrayim that night. One must feel as if he was just freed from
>   slavery. A slave owns nothing. Only a free man can own things. A slave
>   can never invite someone to his meal. Therefore, before we begin our
>   first meal as free men, we declare that we would like to invite
>   whomever would like to come. Even though we know that no one can hear
>   us, we make the declaration to demonstrate to ourselves that we were
>   just freed from slavery.

Another point is we are saying that we acknowledge that part of the mitzvah of matzah is to ensure that everyone is able to partake of the matza. We therefore announce that we have invited others to be part of the group and we have done our best to ensure that everyone can eat. If somehow someone cannot, we have been ready to have them join our group.

> Alternatively, the Vilna Gaon says that the mitzvah of matzah is
>   connected to the mitzvah of tzedakah. The Yerushalmi in Bava Basra
>   says that there is an inyan to give maos chitin before Pesach to
>   enable people to acquire matzah. Based on this we can suggest that the
>   reason why we make an open invitation at the onset of the Seder is
>   because the mitzvah of matzah requires us to ensure that others will
>   have matzah as well. The passage begins with the words Ha lachma anya,
>   which means this is the poor man’s bread [that our fathers ate in
>   Mitzrayim] referring to the matzah. As we mention the matzah, it is
>   imperative that we invite others to join, as the mitzvah of matzah
>   demands.

While it would have been too late to ask anyone to join us for the korbon Pesach, the "kol dichfin" used to be said just before the shechitah of the korbon Pesach. While we can no longer do that, we are announcing that if the korbon Pesach were instituted we would be shechting for a group and we want people to join us in a group for the zecher lekorbon.

> Ha lachma anya continues by stating, “Kol d’tzrich yeisei v’yifsach –
>   whoever needs should come and eat the korban Pesach. Why is it
>   necessary to invite people to eat from the korban Pesach?
>
> Perhaps this invitation is not meant for poor people alone, but for
>   anyone, even someone with the means to eat his own korban. The reason
>   for this is because there is a dispute in the Mishnah in Pesachim 91a
>   whether one may shecht a korban Pesach for an individual or if it must
>   be shechted for a group of people. We pasken that the korban Pesach
>   may be shechted for an individual. However, the Rambam writes in
>   Hilchos Korban Pesach (2:2) that ideally one should shecht the korban
>   Pesach only for a group of people, not for an individual. It is
>   conceivable that it is for this reason that we declare an open
>   invitation to join in the eating of the korban Pesach.